# Need some help reviewing a script pulling links from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I'm using a Python script from a Kodi addon I have tested as successfully pulling audio and would like to make it work with another website, but aren't sure why it's not working.

An example of what I need pulling from the following website for each episode is as follows (4 fields required highlighted in **bold**:

[Target website](https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1) & 
[Data I'm trying to scrape .pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5ht7kkg84tcxsr/example-html.pdf?dl=0)

The problem I'm having is that the above site has really poor use of headers etc. and it's all jumbled into one big mess. All of the guides I've seen refer to  or class= headers, but this doesn't seem to be a thing on this website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Code I'm using here*:

```
import os
import sys
import urllib
import urlparse
#import xbmcaddon
#import xbmcgui
#import xbmcplugin
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def build_url(query):
    base_url = sys.argv[0]
    return base_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(query)

def get_page(url):
    # download the source HTML for the page using requests
    # and parse the page using BeautifulSoup
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

def parse_page(page):
    songs = {}
    index = 1
    # the sample below is specific for the page we are scraping
    # you will need to view the source of the page(s) you are
    # planning to scrape to find the content you want to display
    # this will return all the <a> elements on the page:
    # <a href="some_url">some_text</a>
    for item in page.find_all('image'):
        # the item contains a link to an album cover
        if item['href'].find('.jpg') > 1:
            # format the url for the album cover to include the site url and url encode any spaces
            album_cover = '{0}{1}'.format(sample_page, item['href'].replace(' ', '%20'))
        # the item contains a link to a song containing '.mp3'
        if item['href'].find('.mp3') > 1:
            # update dictionary with the album cover url, song filename, and song url
            songs.update({index: {'album_cover': album_cover, 'title': item['href'], 'url': '{0}{1}'.format(sample_page, item['href'])}})
            index += 1
    return songs

def build_song_list(songs):
    song_list = []
    # iterate over the contents of the dictionary songs to build the list
    for song in songs:
        # create a list item using the song filename for the label
        li = xbmcgui.ListItem(label=songs[song]['title'], thumbnailImage=songs[song]['album_cover'])
        # set the fanart to the albumc cover
        li.setProperty('fanart_image', songs[song]['album_cover'])
        # set the list item to playable
        li.setProperty('IsPlayable', 'true')
        # build the plugin url for Kodi
        # Example: plugin://plugin.audio.example/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theaudiodb.com%2Ftestfiles%2F01-pablo_perez-your_ad_here.mp3&mode=stream&title=01-pablo_perez-your_ad_here.mp3
        url = build_url({'mode': 'stream', 'url': songs[song]['url'], 'title': songs[song]['title']})
        # add the current list item to a list
        song_list.append((url, li, False))
    # add list to Kodi per Martijn
    # http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=209948&pid=2094170#pid2094170
    xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItems(addon_handle, song_list, len(song_list))
    # set the content of the directory
    xbmcplugin.setContent(addon_handle, 'songs')
    xbmcplugin.endOfDirectory(addon_handle)

def play_song(url):
    # set the path of the song to a list item
    play_item = xbmcgui.ListItem(path=url)
    # the list item is ready to be played by Kodi
    xbmcplugin.setResolvedUrl(addon_handle, True, listitem=play_item)

def main():
    args = urlparse.parse_qs(sys.argv[2][1:])
    mode = args.get('mode', None)

    # initial launch of add-on
    if mode is None:
        # get the HTML for http://www.theaudiodb.com/testfiles/
        page = get_page(sample_page)
        # get the content needed from the page
        content = parse_page(page)
        # display the list of songs in Kodi
        build_song_list(content)
    # a song from the list has been selected
    elif mode[0] == 'stream':
        # pass the url of the song to play_song
        play_song(args['url'][0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample_page = 'https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1'
    addon_handle = int(sys.argv[1])
    main()
```

Comment: The page you are trying to extract data from is JSON, not HTML. You will get nowhere with an HTML parser like beautifulsoup.